# Where can I find the debug console in azure scm site?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I created a resource group and a web app in azure. After deployment I went to the https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net url to go to debug console and pip install flask library. But according to documentation I do not see any debug options.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can see you mentioned the 2 tags: Azure Functions and Azure Web App Service and with some Python package code `pip install flask library`. So, Assuming the Language Runtime is Python.

**In Azure Functions**:

- I have Created Python Function App available to only Linux both in **`Consumption, App Service Plans and Premium Hosting Plans`** where I found the below options and also Kudu SCM Site are available only for App Service Plans and Premium Hosting Plans for Azure Functions:

[image]

**In Azure App Service**:

- Python App Service on Windows is no longer supported as mentioned in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask,windows,azure-portal,vscode-deploy,deploy-instructions-azportal,terminal-bash,deploy-instructions-zip-azcli#2---create-a-web-app-in-azure).
- I have Created the Python Web App in Linux OS and Premium App Service Plan:

[image]

**Debug Console available for Windows OS Hosted Functions/Web Apps**:

***1.  Function App (DotNet Language) Hosted in Windows OS***:

[image]

***2.  Angular Web App Hosted in Windows OS***:
[image]

You can go through the MS Docs of [App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/) and [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) QuickStart Section to know what OS Kinds are supported for the available Languages.